# How to pass nested vectors to the GPU in Julia

Tags: julia, gpu

I'm trying to pass a nested `Vector` to a GPU kernel, however I cannot get it to work. Here's a minimal example:

```
using CUDA

function kernel(data::CuDeviceVector{CuDeviceVector{Float64, 1}, 1}) 
    # Do nothing for now
end

# Build a vector of 10 floats
floats = Vector{Float64}()
for i in 1:10
    push!(floats, Float64(1))
end

# Wrap the vector in another vector
outer = Vector{CuArray{Float64}}()
push!(outer, floats |> CuArray)

# Upload to the GPU
final = outer |> CuArray

# Invoke the kernel
@cuda threads=1 kernel(final)
```

I first build a `Vector{Float64}`, then a `Vector{CuArray{Float64}}` and finally a `CuArray{CuArray{Float64}}` which I then try to call the kernel with. The error occurs at `final = outer |> CuArray`:

```
ERROR: LoadError: CuArray only supports element types that are stored inline
```

How can I use nested `Vector`s with the GPU?

Comment: It doesn't work on purpose: GPU only likes arrays with inline elements. Vectors of vectors are vectors of pointers to non-contiguous other allocations in memory. I don't know strategies to fix this, though, so I'll let someone else answer. (You could try StaticArrays, though.)